# How to use interface builder for advanced editing of components?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

In interface builder when I add a UITextField I saw a lot of properties in the inspector window. Especially, I saw the accessibility properties but I do not understand them. Is there any official video or tutorial which helps in understanding the all properties for all UI components?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs are always a good place to start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW5).

Comment: Thank you I will check the document

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Apple's own docs regarding Accessibility would help:

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/accessibility.html

or

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html